# Problems downloading artifact - error reading signed content

Tags: pydev

I was just installing Ubuntu and added Eclipse (Indigo) to it.  When I tried to add `pydev` to it I kept on getting this kind of error about halfway through the install.  Strangely, when opening Eclipse (Indigo) on my other system on Windows 7 ( I already have PyDev installed here before, so this is supposed to get updates only), I am getting the same error.  See below:

> Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.0.0.201311051910.
>   Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7380103325324291237.jar

Like, a lot of them.

Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks,
dh

Answer (score 23):

Not really an answer, but hopefully helpful: I got these errors as well when trying to install PyDev on Ubuntu 12.04. I worked around the problem by unselecting "Show only the latest versions of available software" and selected the 2.6.0 version I know worked on another system.

Comment: This worked for me, too on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I could go as high as version 2.8.2. The only version not working so far is 3.0. I Also have big problems using newer versions of Eclipse like "Kepler". On those eclipse versions the installation is no problem but the plugin does not seem to get loaded after restart. E.g. there are no PyDev entries in the "New -> Project" menu.

Comment: Confirmed. Also works with an another older version. I tried PyDev 2.7.3 (also have Python version 2.7.3) and was installed without any problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for 2.6.0. Any specific reason why Eclipse Galileo is unable to support PyDev 3.6.0?

Comment: In [pydev manual](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html), 3.8 and older are restricted to pydev 2.8 (the manual doesn't explain why), but it also says java7 is required to run the latest ones. Maybe that's related?

Answer (score 1):

from: http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

> Important requisite
>
> PyDev now requires java 7 in order to run. If you don't have java 7,
>   the update process may appear to succeed, but PyDev will simply not
>   show in the target installation. Please double-check if you're using a
>   java 7 vm in about > installation details > configuration before
>   trying to install PyDev.
>
> **Eclipse 3.8 onwards is required for the latest versions of PyDev (if
>   you need to use an earlier version of Eclipse, stick to PyDev 2.8.x).**

Which version of Eclipse are you running? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and the Software Center serves me Eclipse 3.7.

To install 2.8.x in Eclipse, do as bohrax mentioned: unselect "Show only the latest versions of available software" and select the 2.8.x.