# How do I solve this error in the installation of pydev to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, installation, pydev

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1859999621544153058.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1859999621544153058.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile220918655411117184.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile220918655411117184.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6399870224880355539.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6399870224880355539.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3207588695697611376.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3207588695697611376.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2655711214167315759.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2655711214167315759.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3275296877605117137.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3275296877605117137.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3365690189453389652.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3365690189453389652.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile769891602874206282.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile769891602874206282.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3839712619392898292.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3839712619392898292.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile816928325933804340.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile816928325933804340.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5364494705520475285.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5364494705520475285.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7620410059700841148.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7620410059700841148.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5503962215419916520.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5503962215419916520.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile9174931602572798959.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile9174931602572798959.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7280412207836020651.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7280412207836020651.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1668068989976575365.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1668068989976575365.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8657662492011017259.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8657662492011017259.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4065212375412251235.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4065212375412251235.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2655488678408280510.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2655488678408280510.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4140294747756580156.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4140294747756580156.jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916925/problems-downloading-artifact-error-reading-signed-content

Comment: Andrejs' comment above points to the answer for me.  (Install version 2.8.2 instead of 3.0) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

bro, look for the Installing with the zip file middle part of the page