# Installing PyDev into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I've read information from 7 different sites and read a number of posts regarding installing PyDev using eclipse.

Every time I run the add new software as instruction, I encounter the following error

```
Error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2898089162481869708.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2898089162481869708.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile801192414106119940.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile801192414106119940.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6168313931351907508.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6168313931351907508.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7073699876012619363.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7073699876012619363.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4159291415077654942.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4159291415077654942.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5274455020976568652.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5274455020976568652.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4062120571797614987.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4062120571797614987.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1894338590812591599.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1894338590812591599.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7632037949878964195.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7632037949878964195.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3154135008542135846.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3154135008542135846.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8956545440967332177.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8956545440967332177.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8187482656751816692.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8187482656751816692.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1603347679097356963.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1603347679097356963.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6428936156364707912.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6428936156364707912.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6661494086671818853.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6661494086671818853.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8160203079001172934.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8160203079001172934.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile907264170518945675.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile907264170518945675.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3871130954619307455.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3871130954619307455.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4556002555923476904.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4556002555923476904.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8166172504257201044.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8166172504257201044.jar
```

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Lots of other questions about this. The solution seems to be either install a new version of Eclipse or an older version of PyDev.

Comment: Yes, updading to kepler, eclipse 4.3, allowed me to install  pydev 3.3.3.20.... etc, where previously I was getting same errors as you. There is lots of good information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337526/how-to-upgrade-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers-from-juno-to-kepler

Comment: Yup, figured it out earlier today.  I had trouble getting PyDev to show up in Eclipse after successfully loading it.  If that happens, make sure you have Java JDK 8, apparently.  Once I updated my Java, PyDev showed up no problem.  Now to learn Eclipse...

Comment: The Install Page (http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) says: "Eclipse 3.8 onwards is required for the latest versions of PyDev (if you need to use an earlier version of Eclipse, stick to PyDev 2.8.x).".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems downloading artifact - error reading signed content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916925/problems-downloading-artifact-error-reading-signed-content)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in Eclipse 3.7 (it can't read the signature done in the PyDev plugin -- this is a bug fixed on Eclipse 3.8).

So, in short, you need Eclipse 3.8 onwards in order to install PyDev using the update site (and also, PyDev now requires java 7 -- as a note, LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ which is a commercial counterpart of PyDev is standalone and has all requisites builtin).