# Unable to install gradle plugin in RAD 8

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

When trying to install Gradle plugin in RAD 8 (JDK 1.7) using "`Help->Install New Software->[http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOzLS/gradle](http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle) -> Extensions ->Gradle IDE.

The installation fails with below error. How can I fix it?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=bootProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6349333368928430899.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6349333368928430899.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3533168071782523038.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3533168071782523038.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.toolingapi,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6100590399698741916.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6100590399698741916.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5626455591177320598.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5626455591177320598.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4681470222750675595.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4681470222750675595.jar
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same type of problem encountered here:
[Problems downloading artifact - error reading signed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916925/problems-downloading-artifact-error-reading-signed-content)

The explanation there (uncheck the 'only show latest' box on the installation option) implies a version mismatch between the version of Eclipse you are using under the covers of Rational Application Developer 8, and the version required by the Gradle IDE plugin provided by Spring Source.  You probably need to investigate what version of Eclipse you are using and compare it to the requirements of Gradle IDE.